# Space in text file are show as "?" in C#

Tags: c#

I am exporting a text file from excel and read it in C#.
The file has spaces, e.g. a line may look like this:

```
ICP RADIO ALTIMETER,,,icpExpHash,,,Header
```

my code to read it is this:
....

```
    if (File.Exists(commandFile))
    {
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(commandFile);
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var cmds = line.Split(',').ToList();
            cmdFile.Add(cmds);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", cmds));

        }
        file.Close();
```

why do the spaces look like this:

[image]

Comment: check the commandFile encoding

Comment: try to encode it to ascii before manipulating the string

Comment: Then it is probably not a "simple space" (codepoint 32)

Comment: The line have question marks when the default encoding on viewer does not match the encoding of the data.  There may not be anything wrong.  Code may work without changes.

Comment: how can i know the encoding if this is really the issue?
in excel it is s simple space?
those "?" when i print them are not converted back to spaces

Comment: @dandan - Encoding is the issue.

Comment: can you try `StreamReader file = new StreamReader(commandFile, true);`

Comment: StreamReader(commandFile, true) did not help.
I still get the "?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StreamReader(commandFile, Encoding.Default)
```

Did it! though if this is "default" why do i have to specify it?

Comment: Do read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) in the docs